# Преобразование int в double внутри тела метода в C#

Tags: c#, методы, конвертация

Пишу простой метод (калькулятор), принимающий на вход три параметра (string - что за операция будет применена, int a - первый операнд, int b - второй операнд), но нужно как то реализовать операцию деления (т.е. прям внутри метода переконвертировать переменную "result", переменную "a" и переменную "b" в double). Как это можно сделать максимально просто?

```
static int Calc(String Operation, int a, int b)
        {
            
            int result = 0;
            if (Operation == "sum")
            {
                result = a + b;
            }
            else if (Operation == "multiple")
            {
                result = a * b;
            }
            else if (Operation == "minus")
            {
                result = a - b;
            }
            else if(Operation == "devide")
            {
                double.Parse(result) = double.Parse(a) / double.Parse(b);
            }
            
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Привести один из аргументов к double, например `(double)a/b` будет достаточно. Parse - это для строк. Ну, и над результатом никаких операций не нужно. Не забудьте проверить b на ноль, преподаватель наверняка обратить на это внимание. Ну, и метод должен возвращать double.

Comment: А как отдельный if в методе будет возвращать double, если остальные if в этом методе возвращают int?

Comment: Никак. C# язык со строгой типизацией. Поэтому result и должен быть double, и метод должен возвращать double. При этом явно к double результат сложения двух целых не обязательно - это произойдёт автоматически: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/numeric-conversions

Comment: Спасибо Большое за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

С# строго типизированный язык, подобных преобразований он не позволяет делать. Правильно будет написать отдельный метод для каждой операции. Конкретно в методе деления возвращать тип данных double.

В вашей реализации я бы просто убрал devide и вставил его в отдельный метод, который будет возвращать double.

Comment: Ну вообще-то недавно добавили [Generic math](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-7-generic-math/), так что теперь позволительно